# PHPDocumentor 2 and PHP 7 with opcache issues in Doctrine

Tags: php, phpdoc, php-7, opcache, phpdocumentor2

Hopefully someone here knows a thing or 2 about this.

**Short Question**

I am running into an error using phpdoc on the command line, installed via pear on PHP 7.0.2.  The error is:

```
#> phpdoc
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: 
You have to enable opcache.load_comments=1 or zend_optimizerplus.load_comments=1. 
in /usr/local/php5-7.0.2-20160108-102134/lib/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:193
```

How do I fix this error?

**Details**

Opcache is enabled and `opcache.load_comments=1` is in my opcache.ini file, verified by using the commands: `php -i | grep "Opcode"` and `php -i | grep "opcache"` respectively.  Within that .ini file I can verify that changes are loaded by checking enable and disable opcache via that file.

With that said, if I have `opcache.load_comments=1` in my .ini file, why am I still getting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I encountered the same problem while using the PHAR version of PHPDocumentor. The PHAR includes an obsolete version of Doctrine Annotations.

The older version of Annotations is referring to the `opcache.load_comments` setting in `php.ini`, which does not exist in PHP 7:

- [Removed opcache.load_comments configuration directive](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/0a21a0c752a06d25704e04c15464700f75164849).

This has been fixed upstream in Annotations:

- [opcache.load_comments has been removed from PHP 7](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/pull/59).

For now, using the composer version of PHPDocumentor by executing `composer require --dev phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor` resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Now THAT makes sense.  PHP 7 doesn't have that anymore in the ini file, ok that's the reason.  Right now I have it setup with PHAR and pecl, so if I use composer (which I have currently) it will install over phpdocumentor in my current used PHP version?  Just want to make sure before I put in that command.

Answer (score 13):

You can also use composer without manually switching vendors directory contents. Just use:

```
composer require doctrine/annotations
```

to have the latest version of doctrine/annotations (at least 1.2.5 solves the problem)

Comment: Worked for me just fine, with Symfony 2.6.

Comment: "- Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.4.0)"  
dsn't work. solved by doctrine annotations patch 1.2.5

Answer (score 7):

phpDocumentor 2.8.5 is the default version with Ubuntu 16.04. However, php7 support wasn't added until 2.9. I got it working by using the following on the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
wget https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases/download/v2.9.0/phpDocumentor.phar
chmod +x phpDocumentor.phar
sudo mv phpDocumentor.phar /usr/local/bin/phpDocumentor-2.9.phar
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpDocumentor-2.9.phar /usr/local/bin/phpdoc
```

If you installed phpDocumentor from pear, use the following to remove it:

```
sudo pear uninstall phpdoc/phpDocumentor
```

Comment: absolutely best answer so far for devops systems. It does not require running ad-hoc composer commands that pulls 62M of composer source and require deep linking to a final command path. This simple script got me a .phar I could use, put in place that works perfectly with our 7.0.10 docker builds with no problems!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks deepdivedylan for links. However, `composer require --dev phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor` did not solve my problem. But reading through the links and downloading [doctrine annotations patch 1.2.5](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations/releases/tag/v1.2.5) worked fine. Just download archive and replace vendor/doctrine/annotations folder with its contents.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in /home/vasu/work/hosting/prekkha/app/autoload.php:11

Comment: solved. not "replace folder", but "replace content" - merge

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version of phar from [github releases](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/releases) .

The link from website is to an older version of it.