# using phpdocumentor with Symfony3

Tags: symfony, pear, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I am wanting to use [phpDocumentor](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2) with Symfony3. since they are not compatable with eachother as explained [here](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/pull/1845) I have installed phpDocumentor using pear as recomended.

My buidl.xml calls it like this.

```
<target name="phpdoc" description="Generate API documentation using PHPDocumentor">
    <exec logoutput="true" command="/usr/bin/phpdoc -d ${source} -t ${basedir}/build/api" />
</target>
```

and when I run `$ phing`

I get the following error.

```
MyProject > phpdoc:

 [exec] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/username/workspace/MyProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/src/phpDocumentor/Bootstrap.php on line 178
```

there is no `dompdf/` folder in my `vendor/` directory since it was not installed using `composer`

Is there anything else that I can use?
Is there a way of stopping phpdoc looking for a composer.json file and using the `vendor` directory of the project?

Comment: Why don't you use Symfony's own documentor Sami (https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Sami) ? It is easy to use with Symfony

Comment: thanks @ShahrozeNawaz, I'll have a look at it. I would still be interested to find out how to ght phpdoc to work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That'll likely be a bug.  Right now, the PEAR and Composer installations might be unreliable.  The development team recommends the PHAR instead, at least for now -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1859

Comment: installation vis PHAR is nicely documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958319/phpdocumentor-2-and-php-7-with-opcache-issues-in-doctrine/39730825#39730825)