# Errors to migrate from PHP 5.6.3 to PHP 7.0.2

Tags: php, symfony

Previously it worked with the version PHP 5.6.3, Symfony2, Doctrine2 and everything worked very well. I decided to migrate to PHP 7.0.2, I'm still using Symfony2 and Doctrine2, but my website has stopped working and when I check the php_error.log file, it shows me the following error:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
You have to enable opcache.load_comments=1 or zend_optimizerplus.load_comments=1.
```

Any help to solve this error I am very grateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPDocumentor 2 and PHP 7 with opcache issues in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958319/phpdocumentor-2-and-php-7-with-opcache-issues-in-doctrine)

Comment: opcache.load_comments=1 is removed from PHP 7.0. +1 for the above thread suggest by @aynber :)